# AngularJS read data from JSON

Tags: json, angularjs

hello I am new on angular and i come again to have some help.
I try to get datas from a json file : teams.json but it doesn't work
my controller is like this :

```
app.controller('TeamController', ['$http', function($http){
    var liste = this;
    liste.teams = [];    
    $http.get('teams.json').success(function(data){
        liste.teams = data;
    });
}]);
```

and in my html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="teamStats">

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="TeamController">
        <!--
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BODY CONTENT        
        -->
        <div id="wrap" >
                <div class="container"> 
                    <div >
                        <ul>
                          <li ng-repeat="team in liste.teams">{{team.name + team.win}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div> 
        </div>          
        <!--
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% END OF BODY CONTENT     
        -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Many thanks in advance ! hope someone see where i am wrong
I did a plunker for easier understanding
[myPlunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UQmYltseLgNiFQ2EbmSP?p=preview)

Best regards,
Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i think i know now why it doesn't work !! ng-repeat, ng-view, ng-include and others use AJAX to load templates. The problem is that the browser by default does not allow AJAX requests to files located on your local file system (for security reasons). Therefore you have two options:

Run local web server that will serve your files
Tell your browser to allow local files access

Thanks for help all !! Thanks to Vadim explanation !! And thanks a lot zsong ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your controller to this

```
  app.controller('TeamController', ['$http', '$scope',
    function($http, $scope) {
      var liste = this;
      $scope.liste = {};
      $scope.liste.teams = [];
      $http.get('teams.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.liste.teams = data;
      });
    }
  ]);
```

And fix your json file. You need to remove the additional `,`s

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/jeHnvykYLwVZLsRLznRI?p=preview

Comment: Why can't you just do `$scope.liste = {teams : []};` well kidding!! :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your help !! :) I tried my html in plunker and now that is working ! But I still have trouble in localhost ... my page is blank. I think wamp is doing something bad ...